# Change html element's attribute inside html-script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

let's say I have a mark-up like this:

```
<script>
    var doSomething = function () {
        var container = $('.container');
        var list = $('#result-list');
        list.find('.result').attr('id', 'x');
        container.append(list.html());
    };
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="result-list">
    <div class="result"></div>
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="doSomething();">DO</a>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

I can't change `div` id attribute which is placed inside `html-script`. I don't know what or where is the problem. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Can `script` tag have a `div` element?

Comment: Yes, while you set its `type` to `html-script`. I use it for something like template in my markup

Comment: @hjpotter92 It can have whole HTML..

Comment: @SaberAmani dont use `.` in your className.And what is issue..please rephrase your question

Comment: @Pilot well, how jquery knows it is an id or a class?

Comment: dont use <div class=".container"> use <div class="container">

Comment: `.` implies CSS selector for class

Comment: @SaberAmani jQuery selector `$('.className')`. dont specify `.` in markup. `.` is  CSS selector for class

Comment: @SaberAmani dont put `.` in html element class name

Comment: Oh.. I got that, but It's not the problem, There is no dot(.) in original html.

Comment: @SaberAmani can you prepare fiddle demonstrating your issue..post complete rendered html and js

Comment: It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/as2q3/).

Comment: @hjpotter92 it doesn't work see that id has not been modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this.

```
var doSomething = function () {
    var container = $('.container');
    var list = $('#result-list');
    container.append(list.html());
     container.find('.result').attr('id','x');
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/as2q3/1/)

Comment: but I can't understand what is different? Can you explain?

Comment: you are applying attribute on '.result' in script tag but in above code I apply attribute in container div after picking the .result from script tag

Comment: @RakeshKumar why can't one apply attribute on '.result' in script tag , where as '.html()' jquery function work's

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var doSomething = function () {
        var container = $('.container');
        var list = $('#result-list');
        var $result = $(list.html());
        $result.attr('id','x');
        container.append($result);
    };
</script>
```